# Working on Laravel packages not found Class 'Usman\HeloProvider' not found

Tags: laravel

I am making a Laravel package. The error I got is **class not found**. Here is my Provider:

```
<?php

namespace Usman;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HeloProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In config/app.php I define it like this

```
 Usman\HeloProvider::class,
```

In composer.json

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
        "Usman\\": "package/usman/src/"
                }
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: yes I did but it's not working

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure are wrong, you need one more *dir*.

I.e 'usman/dir/src/' or 'dir/usman/src' depends how package is called.
Also you need to update namespace and psr-4 as well..